# ComponentWillUnmount is not getting called React-Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, lifecycle

I know this question already exists on Stack Overflow but most questions and answers are very old. I am working on an app that performs a fetch call to a db inside **componentDidMount** obviously using **react-native**.

I have an **interval** running in **componentDidMount** that calls a query and it works well. Now I need to call `clearInterval(this.interval)` inside **componentWillUnmount** to stop the query and logging in my app.

1. It should be called when I press a save button and navigate with `props.navigation.navigate("new Screen", {params})`
   I read a solution for this where I should use `props.navgiation.replace("Screen")` - but it doesn't work for me
2. The second important part is that **componentWillUnmount** also needs to be called when I press on another tab **(using bottom-tab-navigator)**

I understand that the screens in a stack navigator for example never really unmount. So is there a different way to call **componentWillUnmount** maybe something like when the user left screen( or loses focus on-screen) or user left the specific routeName or something.

My **componentWillUnmount** - really simple:

```
  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.interval)
    console.log("Component did Unmount")
  }
```

it's only called if I go to my LogOut Screen and log-out to be in my LoginScreen again.

(EDIT) My Navigator:

```
const EintragenStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Eintragen: {
      screen: StundenEintragen2,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: "Stundenverwaltung",
        headerTitleStyle:{
          color: "white",
          alignSelf: "center"
        },
        headerStyle:{
          backgroundColor: "#a51717"
        },  
      }
    }
  }
)

const CheckStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Übersicht: StundenChecken,
    Monat: Monatsübersicht2, // Monatsübersicht
    Tag: TagesübersichtDiff, // Tagesübersicht
    Edit: {
      screen: StundenEdit,
      navigationOptions:{
        headerTitle: "Stunden bearbeiten",
        headerTitleStyle: {
          color: "white",
          alignSelf: "center"
        },
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#F39237"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    backBehavior: "history"
  }
);
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  { 
    Eintragen: EintragenStack,     // StundenEintragen
    Checken: CheckStack,
    Logout: Logout
  },
  {
    backBehavior: "history",
    tabBarOptions: {
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 12,
        color: "black"
      },
      activeTintColor: "red",
      activeBackgroundColor: "#ccc"
    }
  }
);
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Login: Auth, //SecondAuth,
  Tabs: Tabs,
});

EintragenStack.navigationOptions = {   
  tabBarIcon: () => {
    return <Icon style={{marginTop: 5}} size={34} name="ios-add-circle-outline" color="green" />;
  }
  
};
CheckStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarIcon: () => {
    return <Icon style={{marginTop: 5}} size={34} name="ios-calendar" color="black" />;
  }
};
Logout.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarIcon: () => {
    return <Icon style={{marginTop: 5}} size={34} name="ios-power" color="red" />;
  }
};

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default AppContainer;
```

---

I actually kind of fixed it for my needs but the problem still exists overall. I don't know if this is a good approach but for me I did it like this:

1. I am calling `checkUnlockHandler` in `componentWillMount` every 30sec.
2. When `checkUnlockHandler` gets to an if that tells it that it doesn't need running anymore I call `clearInterval(this.interval("here is my checkUnlockHandler"))`
3. After that my interval in `componentDidMount` stops running which is good.
4. Problems: Interval still runs in other screens, It feels weird to call a function inside `componentDidMount` wrapped in a interval and inside this function to tell when the interval should stop.

Comment: Check out the navigation events from `react-navigation`: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html, you'll probably want to subscribe to `onDidBlur` or `onWillBlur`.

Comment: can you show us piece of your code where you implement routes?

Comment: @nbokmans I read there are many problems with this do u have an example on how to use it or where to use it ?

Comment: @Luke yh sure updated it

Comment: in docs it says that you have to provide components to stack screens as inline function `component={() => <HomeScreen />}`  but in docs they are using JSX, but still maybe it will give you some directions, sorry i cannot help more https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html

Comment: What is the version of `react-native-screens`? Did you use `useScreens()` or `enableScreens()`. Try to disable it to see whether `componentWillUnmount` is called

Comment: I am not using react-native-screens

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem in using bottom tab navigator and I found simple solution, which works for me.

```
    componentDidMount()
    {
        this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', async () =>{
             this.interval= setInterval(() => { 
                 //---------
             }, 5000);
         });
        this.props.navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
        });
    }
```

also in functional component we can use useEffect with cleanup.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
        this.interval= setInterval(() => { 
                 //---------
        }, 5000);
    });

    return () =>{
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    };
 }, [navigation]);
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved my hours. But I cannot find event 'willFocus' and 'willBlur' maybe obsolote? Instead use 'focus' and 'blur' according to latest 5.x https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/

Comment: New React Navigation Version update the event names. I'll update with new names. Thank you for remind.